# How to use a variable format in `sprintf`

Tags: printf

How should I make a variable format sequence for [sprintf](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#ga6017094d9fd800fa02600d35399f2a2a)?.

```
int i=2,d=9;
String sf;
sprintf(sf,"%%0%d",i);
fprintf(sf,d);
```

While expecting the output.

```
09
```

The compilation fails, with several errors, according the failing change I apply.

```
Invalid cast from type 'String' to type 'char*'
```

Comment: this may help  ..... https://majenko.co.uk/blog/evils-arduino-strings

Comment: Hint: Try `char sf[32];` and then correct the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `sprintf` cannot be used to write data into `String` objects. More precisely, it is possible to come up with a "hackish" way to write the result directly into a `String` object, but the latter is definitely not designed for such use.

   The target buffer should be an array of `char`, not a `String`. Which is what the compiler is telling you.

   ```
   char buffer[64];
   sprintf(buffer, "%%0%d", i);
   ```

   or better

   ```
   char buffer[64];
   snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%%0%d", i);
   ```
2. The format string you used in your `sprintf` will generate `%02` result (since `i` contains `2` at that moment). Why you are expecting `09` is not clear. Why are you expecting the `%` character to disappear is not clear either, considering that the format string seems to be deliberately designed to include it.
3. A `String` object cannot be used as the first parameter of `fprintf`. It is not clear what that `fprintf` is doing in your code.

---

Apparently you are trying to use `sprintf` to generate another format string at run time (using `i` as field width), which is later used to output the `d` variable. In that case that would be something like

```
char format[16];
snprintf(format, sizeof format, "%%0%dd", i);
fprintf(file, format, d);
```

That `fprintf` will indeed output `09`.